# Dns server for specific domain

Tags: linux, networking, dns, arch-linux

Is there a way to define a dns server for a specific domain?
I'm setting up a develop machine with an amp stack and i want to redirect all urls with a specific domain (i.e. project.dev) to 127.0.0.1.
I've done this on OSX with dnsmasq configured in this way:

```
# /etc/dnsmasq.conf

address=/.dev/127.0.0.1
listen-address=127.0.0.1
port=35353
```

and adding a dev file in /etc/resolver with this content

```
# /etc/resolver/dev

nameserver 127.0.0.1
port 35353
```

but this in arclinux with dhcpd doesn't work.

I've tested dnsmasq with `dig test.dev@127.0.0.1 -p 35353` and it works (the address returned is 127.0.0.1) so the problem is the resolver.

I've also tried either put into /etc/resov.conf.head this:

```
# /etc/resolv.conf.head
nameserver 127.0.0.1
port 35353
```

and configure dnsmasq with the default 53 port without luck.

This is my /etc/resolv.conf

```
# /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 127.0.0.1
nameserver 192.168.0.1
```

Comment: if you are asking if you can use one DNS server for queries based on the name xyz.com and another server based on the name abc.com, no not in any OS I've ever worked with. DNS servers are tied to an interface, at the same level that IP address and Default Gateway are defined, so in order to do that you need an additional interface.

Comment: Note that you can run a local DNS server though, and forward NX responses for lookup by another DNS server, just like you do with DNSMasq.

Comment: ok so how can I configure arch to use my local host for DNS queries as first and then forward the query if it doesn't ends with .dev?

Comment: thats what you can't do. there is no selectivity to it.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options here; either you need to configure the DNS server at 192.168.0.1 to resolve ".dev" to 127.0.0.1, or run dnsmasq and route *all* your requests through that, much as you did with OSX previously.

The multiple nameservers in `resolv.conf` are tried *in order* - that is, if the top one is unreachable, the second will be used. *Getting an NXDOMAIN or SRVFAIL response from the top server does not count as a failure for this case*.

I have the same config set up here, though now I have control of the remote DNS server (using unbound) I was able to cast ".local" to resolve to 127.0.0.1. Previously I did this with dnsmasq - the only thing you really need to do is to tell dnsmasq three things;

**no-resolv**: Don't look for upstream nameserver in the `resolv.conf` file. Since that's just going to contain `127.0.0.1`, that'll give you a recursion headache.

**server=192.168.0.1** or wherever your remote DNS server is - where should dnsmasq look to if it can't find the answer to your question in its local config? You could also use something like '8.8.8.8' here (Google's public DNS service).

**address/.dev/127.0.0.1** - Match any requests for "*.dev" to "127.0.0.1".

With that, and the `nameserver=127.0.0.1` directive in `resolv.conf.head`, you should be set.

Comment: The idea of configure the DNS server at 192.168.0.1 is great, but not suitable in my case because i move through multiple networks. At the end I've used dnsmasq to respond at every dns query and forward all not .dev query. In this way I've obtained a dns cache too. The problem were the port property in `/etc/resov.conf.head` that is not standard and works only on osx. Thank you very much for answer!

Comment: Yeah - it's not possible for everyone, because of course some people also don't have access to configure their DNS server in work, or it might be just a router or some thing which can't be configured as easily. I mentioned it just because it's *possible* to achieve this in that way, and in some cases it's an easier solution, especially if as in our case you want to make that alias available to multiple users, or on different platforms (that works on windows too, for instance). Whatever works!